# How to inject property into Aspect logging class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aspectj

I am having trouble injecting a property into `LoggingAspect` class. Imaging I have an AspectJ class:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
   private IBoc theBo;

   /** getter and setter **/
}
```

This is the BOC:

```
public interface IBoc {
}

public class BocImpl implements IBoc {
}
```

and the Spring configuration for BOC:

```
<beans ...>
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

   <bean id="theBoc" class="org.huahsin.BocImpl"/>
</beans>
```

In applicationContext.xml file, I configure the AspectJ in this way:

```
<beans...>
   <bean id="theLog" class="org.huahsin.LoggingAspect">
      <property name="theBo" ref="theBoc"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

How could I inject `theBo` in `LoggingAspect` class?

---

**Update on 17 Oct 2012**

I found some clue here. If I remove the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`, the member variable `theBo` in class `LoggingAspect` will not be null. If I have that code, theBo will be null.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? As far as I understand it should work fine.

Comment: Try to annotate theBo with @Resource annotation and let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Normally `Spring` is responsible for both creating and configuring beans. `AspectJ` aspects, however, are created by the `AspectJ` runtime. You need `Spring` to configure the aspect that `AspectJ` has created. For the most common case of singleton aspects such as yours `LoggingAspect` aspect above, `AspectJ` defines an `aspectOf()` method that returns the aspect instance. You can tell `Spring` to use the `aspectOf()` method as a factory method for obtaining the aspect instance.

For e.g.:

```
  <beans>      
      <bean name="loggingAspect"
        class="org.huahsin.LoggingAspect"
        factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="theBo" ref="theBoc"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="theBoc" class="org.huahsin.BocImpl"/>
  </beans>
```

**UPDATE:**

Define factory method in your class:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private IBoc iBoc;

    private static LoggingAspect instance = new LoggingAspect();

    public static LoggingAspect aspectOf() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setiBoc(IBoc iBoc) {
        this.iBoc = iBoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error -> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingAspect' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/auditlog-spring-context.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf'

Comment: Try to add the following line into your spring configuration: <context:load-time-weaver/>. Also dont forget to add: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

Comment: Do you have any shortcut on this error? -> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar

Comment: OK. remove that load-time-weaver, add annotation to your aspect @Configurable, add <context:spring-configured /> in your spring xml and remove factory-method="aspectOf". If this works I will edit the answer. For the above error you can look here: http://www.dotkam.com/2010/10/12/running-spring-aspectj-tests-with-maven/

Comment: The Configurable thing not working. Rgd the LoadTimeWeaver issue, I need to find out how could I set specify the `-javaagent` argument in WAS Liberty Profile server because I am not using Tomcat as my local server.

Comment: These SO questions refers to the similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541957/spring-unable-to-inject-in-aspect, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343952/spring-dependency-injecting-an-annotated-aspect

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis I though `aspectOf()` was generated automatically. Maybe thats only for `*.aj` files?

Comment: Actually I have never used aspect my self, I was using simple AOP logging. Try to create aspectOf() method your self how I showed in the answer.